# Data is not visualizing in the GeoServer

Tags: javascript, java, postgis, open-source, geoserver

I wanted to visualize my shp file in the GeoServer. But it gives this error. Could you please tell me how i can solve this issue?
[image]

Comment: Is your server headless? Are you running java 17 with our reading the GeoServer release notes?

Comment: Yes, i have installed JAVAjdk_x64_windows_hotspot_17.0.6_10.

Comment: https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/production/java.html#running-on-java-17